# How to auto increment mysql id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want increment id by 6, means when next entery enter then 8, then another enter 14 like this one. how to do that.

```
                 +--------------------------+-------+
                 | username               | user_id |
                 +--------------------------+-------+
                 | yanki                    | 1     |
                 | dude                     | 2     |
                 +--------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: And what is the logic behind it ?

Comment: means when entry enter i didn't want increment by 1 i want increment by 6.

Comment: Why 6? Not 5, 1 or 11?

Comment: yes anyone what you want. just increment what you want for next id's

Answer (score 1):

Check the [auto_increment_increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment), from the docs:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 1     |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE autoinc1
    -> (col INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
  Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> SET @@auto_increment_increment=10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 10    |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO autoinc1 VALUES (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT col FROM autoinc1;
+-----+
| col |
+-----+
|   1 |
|  11 |
|  21 |
|  31 |
+-----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Just keep in mind that this is per database not per table.

> It is not possible to restrict the effects of these two variables to a single table;

Comment: This would apply on all tables

Comment: This is not solution :( i want increment when another value insert then increment by 10 and so on.. not 1

Comment: that's what the `auto_increment_increment` is for, it will increment in steps of 10